# Read content Uri from File from SharedPreferences and get persistent permission on it

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver

my app can be called from file explorer via app chooser.
I catch the given `contentUri` from the transmitted PDF file and save the content uri useing `sharedPreferences`.

If I start my app again, I want to open the saved PDF file (reading the contentUri from from sharedPreferences) again.
But no file chooser should be opened anymore.

But I can't call `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` via the App Chooser because I get the `uri` direct from `sharedpreferences`. I also can't call
`getContentResolver().takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags);`.

So I can't get access to this file again.

How can I get permanent access to the file. Is copying to `INTERNAL_STORAGE` really the only solution?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: "I catch the given contentUri from the transmitted PDF file" -- do you mean that you are getting the `Uri` by responding to an `Intent` like `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_SEND`?

Comment: Yes. From app chooser I get an intent from which I fetch the contenturi. In manifest I declared the intentFilter with Open_Document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I catch the given contentUri from the transmitted PDF file

Based on your response to my question in the comments, I am interpreting this as: you are getting the `Uri` from an inbound `Intent` to one of your activities, such as via `ACTION_VIEW` or `ACTION_SEND`.

> and save the content uri useing sharedPreferences

That is not going to work.

Think of the `Uri` as being akin to a URL to a password-protected Web site. So long as the session cookie is good, the URL works, but as soon as that session expires or the cookie is cleared, the URL is useless.

Similarly, [that `Uri` is good at most for your running process](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html), and there is nothing that you can do about that.

If you need long-term access to the content, either:

- Make a copy of that content in some file that you control, or
- Stop responding to `ACTION_VIEW`/`ACTION_SEND`, and instead use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` and `takePersistableUriPermission()`